# Opening or downloading a PDF document from a php variable

Tags: php, jquery, variables, pdf

I have a piece of code which polls a CRM system and finds a specific document via a URL..... from the document which is found, this is then added to a PHP variable - however if I then print the PHP variable it's just garbage.  How can I take the PHP variable and out the contents to PDF (it is a PDF already stored in the variable).... so it can be either downloaded or opened to screen?

Here is the code being used:

```
**$url = "accounting/invoices/55120.pdf?template=30&api_key='My-API-Key'";
$pdf = $thisbooks->get($url, array(), array('decode_json' => false));
// Ensure the response looks like a PDF
if (!preg_match('/^\%PDF\-1\.4\s/', $pdf)) {
  $thisbooks->log('ERROR: Unexpected response: is it a PDF?', $pdf, 'error');
}
$thisbooks->log('Fetched PDF', $pdf);
print $pdf;**
```

Now when I print the $pdf variable I can see the script code, but it doesn't do anything else.....

Thanks in advance

Damian

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use `file_get_contents` to read your variable?

or use this header: `header('Content-type: application/pdf');`

If you send your code maybe we can help more.

Comment: Hi,    Sorry would help if I added the code.  This has now been added.  Damian